# How can I sort values in AngularJS?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. How can  I filter the `count and quality` value in table. I want to search each and every count and quality values...[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OgdpAcDP20Fpm0NjjQPL?p=preview)
 if we select `yarn count` it's not filtering, the table displaying like Empty or Nill, please help for the same...

HTML:-

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group form-group-default"> 
    <label>Count</label> 
    <select data-ng-model="searchtable.count" id="count" ng-options="item.colorshades[0].count for item in sryarnorders" class="form-control">
        <option value="">All</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 form-group form-group-default">
    <label>Quality</label>
    <select data-ng-model="searchtable.quality" id="quality" ng-options="item.colorshades[0].quality for item in sryarnorders" class="form-control">
        <option value="">All</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**ng-options:-**

```
ng-options="item.colorshades[0].count for item in sryarnorders"

ng-options="item.colorshades[0].quality for item in sryarnorders"
```

**ng-module:-**

```
data-ng-model="searchtable.count"

data-ng-model="searchtable.quality"
```

**My data:-**

```
 $scope.sryarnorders = [
     {
       "_id": "573d7fa0760ba711126d7de5",
        "user": {
          "_id": "5721a378d33c0d6b0bb30416",
          "displayName": "ms ms"
        },
       "__v": 1,
        "colorshades": [{
          "_id": "573d7fc3760ba711126d7de6",
          "quality": "Home Textiles",
          "count": "yarn count"
        },
        {
    "_id": "579ef3feba3bac040b583b50",
    "color": "56a5b6831746bc1c0b391c7c",
    "quality": "Hall Textiles",
    "count": "carn count"
    }],
        "created": "2016-05-19T08:56:00.997Z",
        "actual_delivery_date": "2016-05-19",
        "ex_india_date": "2016-05-19",
        "ex_factory_date": "2016-05-19",
        "po_delivery_date": "2016-05-19",
        "supplier_name": "Fsa",
        "buyer_name": "e21"
      },

      {
        "_id": "56ffc6d5ab97a73d1066b798",
        "user": {
          "_id": "56ff7bece2b9a1d10cd074a3",
          "displayName": "saravana kumar"
        },
        "__v": 1,
        "colorshades": [{
          "_id": "56ffc723ab97a73d1066b799",
          "quality": "Hall Textiles",
          "count": "burn count"
        }],
        "created": "2016-04-02T13:19:17.746Z",
        "actual_delivery_date": "2016-04-02",
        "ex_india_date": "2016-04-04",
        "ex_factory_date": "2016-04-02",
        "po_delivery_date": "2016-04-02",
        "supplier_name": "Fsa",
        "buyer_name": "Binary hand"
      },

      {
        "_id": "56ffc5e0ab97a73d1066b796",
        "user": {
          "_id": "56ff7bece2b9a1d10cd074a3",
          "displayName": "saravana kumar"
        },
        "__v": 1,
        "colorshades": [{
          "_id": "56ffc608ab97a73d1066b797",
          "quality": "yarn quality",
          "count": "carn count"
        }],
        "created": "2016-04-02T13:15:12.876Z",
        "ex_india_date": "2016-04-02",
        "ex_factory_date": "2016-04-02",
        "po_delivery_date": "2016-04-02",
        "supplier_name": "Fsa",
        "buyer_name": "e21"
      }];
```

I have created Plunker for reference:-[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OgdpAcDP20Fpm0NjjQPL?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct `ng-options` for having only `count` string as value of `<option>`:

```
ng-options="item.colorshades[0].count as item.colorshades[0].count for item in sryarnorders"
```

otherwise the value is all the object.

But for doing what do you want you need to define a new $filter or use

```
filter:{colorshades: [searchtable]}
```

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/suCWn/12/

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, the drop down is perfect, but it's not filtering the value, if we select `yarn count` or any value it's not filtering, the table displaying like Empty or Nill ,so can you please help for the same....and update your plunker as well thank you soo much.....

Comment: the above given filter is not working , can you please look at my plunker for the refference, and please provide the updated plunker as well to get the solution...thanks...